# Python Selenium Webdriver - WebDriverException: Message: The operation is insecure

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to upload a file using selenium firefox webdriver in python.
Even though I'm removing the readonly attribute of the file input type and sending the file location, its erroring out.
Any suggestions to get around this problem would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<form method="POST"enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input readonly="" autocomplete="off" id="formchfile" type="text">
<table >
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td><button id="extgen1227" type="button"> Browse </button></td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input id="formchfilefile" name="ufile" type="file">
</form>
```

**Python Code:**

```
file2=driver.find_element_by_id('formchfilefile')
driver.execute_script("$(arguments[0]).removeAttr(arguments[1]);", file2, 'readonly')
##file2.send_keys('device_ios.csv')
driver.execute_script("$(arguments[0]).val(arguments[1]);", file2, 'hello')
file2.get_attribute('value')
```

**Error:**

```
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 465, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The operation is insecure.
Stacktrace:
    at .val/< (https://172.27.126.119/js/jquery.js:53)
    at c</<.each (https://172.27.126.119/js/jquery.js:33)
    at c</b.prototype.each (https://172.27.126.119/js/jquery.js:26)
    at .val (https://172.27.126.119/js/jquery.js:52)
    at anonymous (https://172.27.126.119/elementList.seam?deviceTab=fan&queryStr=&leftLink=fan line 69 > Function:1)
    at handleEvaluateEvent (https://172.27.126.119/elementList.seam?deviceTab=fan&queryStr=&leftLink=fan:69)
    file2.get_attribute('value')
```

Comment: Why are you not simply trying as `driver.find_element_by_id('formchfilefile').send_keys('path/to/file')`??

Comment: Hi Saurabh, thanks for the reply. As you can see I commented out that part. It's not working either. That's the reason I'm removing the readonly attribute using JavaScript and trying to update its file path.